# Nesting variables in EL

Tags: jsf-2, nested, el

Is it possible to nest variable calls like below in EL using `FacesContext` or other implicit objects like `request`, `session`, etc.?  This of course is not working. I get this error

> Error Parsing: #{myBean.myMethod(#{FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() })}

for this attempt

```
<ui:include src="#{myBean.myMethod(#{FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() })}">
```

Comment: As to your attempt to accept the answer: Unregistered user accounts are backed by a browser cookie and thus tied to a specific PC/browser. You need to register your user account by OpenID so that you will be able to use the same user account from all PCs/webbrowsers. Otherwise you need to go back to the PC/webbrowser from where you have posted the question (if the cookies are not deleted). Once you have registered your user account, moderators will be able to merge any dangling unregistered user accounts with your newly registered account.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed invalid EL syntax. Nesting of `#{}` is disallowed. Just put the whole expression inside the same `#{}`. Plus, the `#{FacesContext}` doesn't exist in Facelets' EL scope, it's `#{facesContext}` and it's already the current instance. Further, you don't necessarily need to specify the entire method name with parentheses if it are getter method already.

So, this should do

```
<ui:include src="#{myBean.myMethod(facesContext.viewRoot.viewId)}">
```

*(note that this still requires a target container with Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 support)*

Answer (score 1):

To add to BalusC's answer, I would like to comment that as a general rule, make your EL expressions as simple as possible and put all the logic -- particularly complex logic, in the Java of the backing bean.   Why not just create a new Java method in MyBean that does what you want and just refer to that?

EL is very powerful but looks to me like its capability is tempting you to put business logic in the presentation layer.

Comment: Although I absolutely agree that great care should be taken that not an ounce of business logic is put into a view, expressions that decide whether something should be rendered or not could definitely be at home in the view. Not every expression should be a simple binding to a property. Also realize that *real* business logic should also not be in the backing bean, which is nearly always just the plumbing between the xhtml view and some business service.